# TagHelper never gets executed in .NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have created a Tag Helper to identify the current active page in my menu. For this, I have followed the following guide to implement the ActiveRouteTagHelper:
https://benjii.me/2017/01/is-active-route-tag-helper-asp-net-mvc-core/

So I created a folder called "Helpers" and added a new class "ActiveRouteTagHelper.cs".
This class contains the following code:

```
namespace MyWebsiteNamespace.Helpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "is-active-route")]
    public class ActiveRouteTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        /* snipped, because this is exactly the same as in the linked document and doesn't matter to my question */
    }
}
```

and I added my tag helper namespace to the _ViewImports.cshtml file like this:

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, MyWebsiteNamespace.Helpers
```

and in my _Layout.cshtml, I have the following code:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a is-active-route class="nav-link pl-0 text-white" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a is-active-route class="nav-link text-white" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can verify that my Tag Helper never gets called because I have put breakpoints in my code that never get triggered.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?